# Which values cannot be represented correctly by a double

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, double, decimal

The Double data type cannot correctly represent some base 10 values. This is because of how floating point numbers represent real numbers. What this means is that when representing monetary values, one should use the decimal value type to prevent errors. (feel free to correct errors in this preamble)

What I want to know is what are the values which present such a problem under the Double data-type under a 64 bit architecture in the standard .Net framework (C# if that makes a difference) ?

I expect the answer the be a formula or rule to find such values but I would also like some example values.

Comment: Use decimal when representing monetary values - that is true..and should be followed whether on 64bit or 32bit arch.

Comment: Or cents (or subcents) as a BigInteger :)

Comment: As to specifying .Net, the 64 architecture, etc. was in case there were any implementation details that had to be taken into account to answer my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any number which cannot be written as the sum of positive and negative powers of 2 cannot be exactly represented as a binary floating-point number.

The common [IEEE formats for](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) 32- and 64-bit representations of floating-point numbers impose further constraints; they limit the number of binary digits in both the significand and the exponent.  So there are maximum and minimum representable numbers (approximately +/- 10^308 (base-10) if memory serves) and limits to the precision of a number that can be represented.  This limit on the precision means that, for 64-bit numbers, the difference between the exponent of the largest power of 2 and the smallest power in a number is limited to 52, so if your number includes a term in 2^52 it can't also include a term in 2^-1.

Simple examples of numbers which cannot be exactly represented in binary floating-point numbers include `1/3`, `2/3`, `1/5`.

Since the set of floating-point numbers (in any representation) is finite, and the set of real numbers is infinite, one algorithm to find a real number which is not exactly representable as a floating-point number is to select a real number at random.  The probability that the real number is exactly representable as a floating-point number is `0`.

Comment: While `10^5000` can not be represented by `double`, in can be exactly represented as a binary floating-point number.

Comment: I'm a little rusty, but I believe that 0 cannot be represented as the sum of positive or negative powers of 2. Can it in fact be represented exactly by a double? I came here specifically for this information, and it seems like it would be possible, but not according to that statement. I want to display a value only if it isn't 0, and I don't want to see some 0.000000132, e.g.

Comment: It also seems like any integer until the maximum could then be represented by a double. Is this why the C++ "round" function returns a double? It can then safely be cast to int, avoiding the possibility of casting 5.9999 to int(5)?

Comment: @ChuckkHubbard: `0` is exactly representable as the sum of no numbers, `0` is `0` is `0` in pretty much any base you care to consider, including binary.  IEEE binary representations include 2 'values' for `0`, one for `+0` and one for `-0`.   They each have only `0`s in all the bits of their fraction and exponent, `-0` has a sign bit of `1`.  Most systems hide the sign of the `0` from programmers and users.

Answer (score 3):

You generally need to be prepared for the possibility that any value you store in a `double` has some small amount of error.  Unless you're storing a constant value, chances are it could be something with at least some error.  If it's imperative that there never be any error, and the values aren't constant, you probably shouldn't be using a floating point type.

What you probably should be asking in many cases is, "How do I deal with the minor floating point errors?"  You'll want to know what types of operations can result in a lot of error, and what types don't.  You'll want to ensure that comparing two values for "equality" actually just ensures they are "close enough" rather than exactly equal, etc.

Comment: Why was this downvoted - there is nothing inherently wrong about it?

Comment: @JonH I'm a bit curious myself.  I suppose technically I didn't answer the question, I attempted to solve the root problem regardless of the actual question asked.

Comment: But your answer helps to answer the question, I will upvote it but I fear this is some sort of retaliation, there is nothing wrong about your statement.

Comment: The question turned out to be more complex than first presumed, so I think it's a perfectly valid answer.
However, I have taken into account that some values cannot be represented in base to, stepping only by 2^-n, which I think should do the trick, just as long as it's not taken to the extreme, yet the components of long double complex still act differently than long double.

As for cpowl(), that question is pretty much answered, though I fail to see why one would not make an implementation treating integer exponents as a special case.

Comment: "Unless you're storing a constant value" - also not true. Try storing 123.1 to double, you'll end up with 123.09999...

Comment: @OndraŽižka The point being if you're storing a constant you know whether or not you have an exact value.  You can store constant values that you know are *exact*.  That doesn't mean every constant can be stored exactly

Answer (score 1):

This question actually goes beyond any single programming language or platform. The inaccuracy is actually inherent in binary data.

Consider that with a double, each number N to the left (at 0-based index I) of the decimal point represents the value N * 2^I and every digit to the right of the decimal point represents the value N * 2^(-I).

As an example, 5.625 (base 10) would be 101.101 (base 2).

Given this calculation, and decimal value that can't be calculated as a sum of 2^(-I) for different values of I would have an incorrect value as a double.

Comment: This just begs the question.  How do I know if a particular base 10 decimal value can be represented as N * 2^-i for a finite i?

Comment: @Servy: http://cs.furman.edu/digitaldomain/more/ch6/dec_frac_to_bin.htm and many other references answer your question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Then you should include that in your answer.  Without it, you are not actually helping him solve a problem, you're just giving him a new problem to solve.

Comment: Actually I have, and plan to continue to use only input values that, as far as I understand it, can be represented in binary, -2.0, 1.75, 0.875, etc. In other words using steps of the form 2^(-n).

Still, complex numbers apparently act differently, which I can only presume has something to do with the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

A float is represented as `s`, `e` and `m` in the following formula

```
s * m * 2^e
```

This means that any number that cannot be represented using the given expression (and in the respective domains of `s`, `e` and `m`) cannot be represented exactly.

Basically, you can represent all numbers between `0` and `2^53 - 1` multiplied by a certain power of two (possibly a negative power).

As an example, all numbers between `0` and `2^53 - 1` can be represented multiplied with `2^0 = 1`. And you can also represent all those numbers by dividing them by `2` (with a `.5` fraction). And so on.

This answer does not fully cover the topic, but I hope it helps.

Comment: You seem to know what you're talking about, so if you please, since I don't actually understand your answer, I have a question.

What I'm doing is basically iterating through the set of values from -2 to +2, stepping by 2^-n, ex. -2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5,2 for n=1.
It has been my presumption that, within reason, this approach will pretty much guarantee that these values will be represented correctly. Am I now to understand that this is a wrong assumption? And what would potentially be a better approach?

Comment: @Zacariaz 2^-n can be represented exactly provided that n fits the range that floats support. In the formula from my answer, s would be +-1, m = 1 and e = n. The binary representation of floats store s, m and e as bits. In your example sequence, 1.5 does not seem to fit because it is not a 2^n item, right? One complication would be for you to generate these 2^n values. I'm not sure Math.Pow is guaranteed to be exact.

Comment: @Zacariaz or maybe you want to take a certain integer number m and multiply that number with all possible values of 2^n? That's possible. I suggest that you try to understand the formula from my answer. It tells you what numbers can be represented. If you can find values for s, m and e then that number can be represented. Otherwise not.