# C# Math.Round issue with x.95

Tags: c#

Just came across one strange issue:

```
Math.Round(113.065, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 113.06
Math.Round(113.075, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 113.08
Math.Round(113.085, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 113.08
```

But...

```
Math.Round(113.095, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 113.1
```

Why is this happening? I'd like my result to be 113.09! Is that possible?

Thx

Comment: Some numbers cannot be accurately described due to how decimal is stored in binary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165216/which-values-cannot-be-represented-correctly-by-a-double

Comment: `Math.Round(113.075, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => **113.08**`

Comment: @Snappawapa: That's not the issue here.

Answer (score 11):

```
Math.Round(113.095, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 113.1
```

That is **even**.  Read it with two decimal places:

***113.10***

10 would be the even part.  The trimmed right zero is just making it look odd *("odd" in the sense of "not even", not to be confused as "odd" meaning "weird")*, but that would be why it is showing that way.

Also, your examples in your question are inaccurate.  Here is the output from those, which would further fortify why you're getting `x.1` as your output:

```
Math.Round(113.065, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 113.06
Math.Round(113.075, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 113.08
Math.Round(113.085, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 113.08
```

Notice that rounding 113.075 `ToEven` results in 113.0**8**, not 113.0**7**.

Full example:

```
Math.Round(113.065, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 113.06
Math.Round(113.075, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 113.08
Math.Round(113.085, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 113.08
Math.Round(113.095, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 113.1
```

Which can also be read as:

```
Math.Round(113.065, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 113.06
Math.Round(113.075, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 113.08
Math.Round(113.085, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 113.08
Math.Round(113.095, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 113.10
```

**If the output in your question is really what you're looking to get... (i.e. if that *really* is your desired output, and you just want to know *what* you have to do to get that output)**

```
Math.Floor(113.065 * 100) / 100 => 113.06
Math.Floor(113.075 * 100) / 100 => 113.07
Math.Floor(113.085 * 100) / 100 => 113.08
Math.Floor(113.095 * 100) / 100 => 113.09
```