# Rounding behaviour of Math.Log

Tags: c#, double, logarithm

I'm trying to determine if a give integer `n` is a power of three. My approach is to take the base 3 log of n and check if there's anything after the decimal point of the result:

```
int n = 243;
double result = Math.Log(n, 3);
Console.WriteLine(result);
if (result % 1 == 0)
{
    return true;
}

return false;
```

Here's the output of the program when I run the above code:

```
5
False
```

I tried doing this another way:

```
        double result = Math.Log(n, 3);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.WriteLine((int)result);
        double remainder = result - (int)result;
        Console.WriteLine(remainder);
        if (remainder == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
```

With n = 243 I get:

```
5
4
0.999999999999999
False
```

Note that with `n=27` `True` is returned as expected. What's going on here? I'm expecting `True` to be returned when n us 243.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Are you querying why 5 - 4 is 0.9999? Standard inability of double to represent certain integers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165216/which-values-cannot-be-represented-correctly-by-a-double

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/4429044/11683.

Comment: Once you have the approximate radix 3 log, round to an integer, raise 3 to that power in exact integer arithmetic, and see if it matches.